# typescript error when spreading `Parameters<F>`

Tags: typescript, parameters, typescript-generics, spread-syntax

This is the [narrowed down code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOBZApgHgDFFcAPKXMAEwGdEAKAOmfTAHMaAuRVgTwEpEAXgB8PMLxH0AUIjmJg3QgBpp-bkxaoO3AAroMAW1wVUNIiMGjEAJRMhUYACq9MBQmIDes%20anuOFcGh4ME1GAx1EfSMTXDMLdVt-Z1d3Lx95X2SFMIiafgBuDMQAX2kSoA) from my actual use case.

```
function wrapMe<F extends (...args: any) => any>(
    f: F,
): (...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F> {
    return function(...args: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> {
        return f(...args);
        //          ^^^^
        // Type 'Parameters<F>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. [2488]
    }
}
```

Why is this a typescript error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#36874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36874).  Until and unless it's resolved, you can work around it either by changing the constraint to make the parameter `any[]` instead of `any`:

```
function wrapMe<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  // -----------------------------> ^^^^^
    f: F,
): (...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F> {
    return function (...args: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> {
        return f(...args);
    }
}
```

or by wrapping `Parameters<T>` in a [variadic tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```
function wrapMe<F extends (...args: any) => any>(
    f: F,
): (...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F> {
    return function (...args: [...Parameters<F>]): ReturnType<F> {
    // ---------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return f(...args);
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgO4CcCGAHAsgUwEYAeAMWXwA8Z8IATAZ2QAoA6dzdAcwYC5lMEAJ4BtALoBKZAF4AfAOGzmwZKuQh+pADTAJ-Nh259kABU6YAtvhroGZWVLnIAStbDoIAFSHZ895ADeKmrobh7qkLCIKAasnDz8ZlhWNnakDvyuMO5ePn7pgcFqIWEoILHxDBIA3EXIAL7AjeDQ8EhoWHj4AExkFNS0jCzscUb8gkKO8hNKdRrI2rr6I5WJ5in4tvZTLqXevv5BxaHZ4S1R7RVjyCIjSZbWm2mykpl7eYd1x6XqVzw1dUajSAA)